# Generate vue.js client from a swagger spec

Tags: vue.js, swagger

I have a swagger/openapi specification. How can I generate a javascript client and then use it in vue.js components, based on that spec?

The [official](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) solution needs to execute a lot of commands, how can I generate the client from pure javascript?

Comment: maybe https://github.com/wcandillon/swagger-js-codegen

Comment: I'm with you. I'm looking for something like http://NSwag.org for https://vuejs.org/ . https://github.com/koumoul-dev/vue-openapi help point me to https://apis.guru/awesome-openapi3 , which I'm guessing is the place we will see something pop-up if someone makes it.

Comment: Try this: [OpenAPI Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/). It generates common JS / TS OpenAPI clients.